# Hibernate takes more time for sql query to execute than in oracle sql developer

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I have query that takes few milliseconds to execute in oracle sql developer and same query takes around 2 mins through hibernate. I set show_sql = true but did not find any clue. 
Below are the details -

Query -

```
select field1 from table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
where t2.status = 'SomeValue';
```

Hibernate query -

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Table1ClassName.class);
criteria.createAlias("table2", "ts", CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ts.status", "SomeValue"));
criteria.setProjection(Property.forName("field1"));
return criteria.list();
```

Generated sql -

```
select
        this_.field1 as y0_ 
    from
        table1 this_ 
    inner join
        table2 ts1_ 
            on this_.ID=ts1_.ID 
    where
        hs1_.STATUS='SomeValue';
```

The query returns approximately 5000 records. Is it the case that converting data into java objects takes time.
Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Of course that is the case. That's not the question you want to ask. The question you want to ask is: can the conversion of 5000 records to entity objects be the source of the extra overhead. The answer to that is: no. The difference is not going to be minutes.

Comment: SQL Developer by default does not retrieve all rows (it think it initially only retrieves 20 or so). What happens if you increase the number of rows SQL Developer retrieves? How long does it take then?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I have increased few records(around 500) still sql developer execute query in few milliseconds only.

Comment: with 500 you are still only retrieving a 10th of the data that hibernate does.